# Ledger Nano S accounts

Tags: ledger-nano-s

If I previously had an account in my Ledger Waller Ethereum desktop app called 'rocket funds', how would this appear in a newly restored ledger or can I only access the funds/wallets by manually creating the custom accounts again? I assume the account names are stored on the actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account names are encrypted using the seed which are then stored on Ledger's server, so the explicit account names will still display after resetting and restoring the Ledger Nano S.